# Why can't I require files which are available due to app.use?

Tags: node.js, require

If a directory has been made available to a node application in the server.js file which sits in the main directory using:

```
app.use("/scripts",express.static(__dirname + "/scripts"));
```

and I attempt to use require from a file inside of that directory (/scripts/custom.js) using:

```
var Testing123       = require('../app/models/article');
```

Is there a reason this is not possible? and is there a solution to that problem?

Edit: In one of my views (views/tree.ejs) I use:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/custom.js"></script>
```

to access my Custom script which sits inside my scripts folder which is made available using `express.static`, Custom uses a web scraper to scrape articles and present them in circles (in the form of an image, title and link) on views/tree.ejs, I now want custom.js to save each article it creates to a mongodb database but to do so, it needs access to things like my Article Schema hence the problem above.

Comment: Please make your question easier to understand; express.static is used to expose a static route, to serve static files (client-side JS, css, etc..)  and here it seems like you want to use a server-side node.js piece of code in an asset folder. Is your `custom.js` supposed to run in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot because Node.js scripts and browser scripts do not run in the same context. Your `app.use` call just exposes a /scripts route that serves assets statically on your HTTP Server.

Your `scripts/custom.js` script seems to be a browser-side script (Because you load it with a script tag inside an `ejs` view) but you want to use `require` inside it and this will not work as this is a Node.js function.

Have a look at [LearnYouNode](https://github.com/rvagg/learnyounode) which is an excellent Node beginner tutorial so that you will understand how modules work in Node and know a bit more about the separation between server-side and client-side JS.